# Deploy react docker container in Azure container instances

Tags: reactjs, azure, docker, azure-container-instances

I'm attempting to deploy a simple react app to azure container instances. However im having an issue with port forwarding in the azure portal.

The image sits in docker-hub in a public repo.

```
docker pull lylediego/monsters-rolodex:22
```

It starts fine on my local host with the below command.

```
docker run -d -p 8000:3000 <image-id>
```

To see app visit

```
http://localhost:8000/monster
```

If anyone has access to azure portal with a subscription, please try and deploy this image to azure container instances and see if you are able to spin it up like it does on localhost.

below  is my dockerfile

```
FROM node:12.2.0-alpine

WORKDIR /app

ENV PATH /app/node_modules/.bin:$PATH

COPY package.json ./

COPY package-lock.json ./

EXPOSE 3000

RUN npm i

COPY . ./

CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

Thanks everyone I appreciate all the effort.

Lyle Diego

Comment: "an issue with port forwarding" How do you deploy your container to ACI (portal, CLI)?

Comment: @Lyle Phillips - I have tried building the image using the above shared `dockerfile` in my local it is failing at COPY statements as [shown here](https://i.imgur.com/Cght1gb.png). Could you check whether you are able to build the image in your local using the above docker file.

Comment: @CSharpRocks in Azure there is network tab where you set the ports that the container exposes.

Comment: @VenkateshDodda-MSFT so in order to do docker build you would need access to the source. Have you been able to pull the image as and then run it with "docker run"

Comment: @LylePhillips , i am able to pull the `node:12.2.0-alpine` image to my local with out any issues.

Comment: That is the issue...it runs fine on local but when i try and spin it up with Azure container instance the container keeps restarting